# API Google Maps, Localização não aparece

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou com um problema na API do google maps, estava funcionando tudo ok quando eu estava emulando meu mapa do android studio para meu celular.
Após eu disponibilizar meu app na google play, os usuario que abaixam, o mapa não aparece para eles, fica como se não tivesse configurado o "google_maps_key".
Imagino que eu esteja fazendo alguma coisa errada ao colocar o app na google play.
Alguém poderia me ajudar? sou iniciante ainda.
caso precisem mais de algumas informações eu disponibilizo
desde já grato

Comment: então adicione as informações, assim as pessoas conseguem lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: Você criou a chave do google maps em modo release?